# how to install pip, gcc, python on another player on linux because device already full

Tags: gcc, pip, installation, device

I have a Nao robot, which runs on Gentoo linux.

my problem is that the root is 97% full, I have another drive

Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                  907096    830868     30148  97% /
/dev/root               907096    830868     30148  97% /
rc-svcdir                 1024        92       932   9% /lib/rc/init.d
cgroup_root              10240         0     10240   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                     10240       124     10116   2% /dev
tmpfs                   513316      2952    510364   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   513316      1552    511764   1% /var/volatile
/dev/mmcblk0p1         7639920    703184   6548644  10% /var/persistent
/dev/sda1               126931      6334    114044   6% /var/persistent
/media/in

I can not install anything, I do not have Pip, GCC and has no place to install anything.

Is it possible to install my modules on other drives?

Thank you.

Comment: note that I can not change the drive because it is on the circuit board

Answer (score 0):

On Nao V5, I use the VM image mounted with Virtual Box to compile the software I need. It's kind of a pain because all the tools are outdated, and don't support modern SSL connections. But you can compile Python modules and C/C++ library on the virtual machine (it has pip and GCC installed) and then transfer them to your machine using SCP.

For info, I went as far as using my own machine as a proxy to pip as pip refused the outdated https requests from Nao.

Nao V6 has some (all?) those tools installed by default in the normal robot. At least Pip was there and I could install some libraries I needed directly in the robot.